# Display an entry after x entries

Tags: database, laravel, logic

I have a foreach loop show entries in the view. How can I spend something after x entries?

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array is numeric index you can use its keys:

```
@foreach($users as $index=>$user)
  @if($index < 10)
    {{$user->name}}
  @else
    {{/*Whatever*/}}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Other wise, you can define a counter:

```
@php($counter=0)
@foreach($users as $user)
  @if($counter< 10)
    {{$user->name}}
  @else
    {{/*Whatever*/}}
  @endif
  @php($counter++)
@endforeach
```

Or as what Ahsan said, you can use the loop variable of Laravel:

```
@foreach($users as $index=>$user)
  @if($loop->index < 10)
    {{$user->name}}
  @else
    {{/*Whatever*/}}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

--EDIT--

Modulo operation will be the best option for you!

```
$show = false;
@foreach($users as $index=>$user)
  // for each 9 entries $show value will be reversed
  @if($loop->index % 9 === 0)
    $show = !show;
  @endif
  @if($show)
    {{$user->name}}
  @else
    {{/*Whatever*/}}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: It works, but not quite how I wanted it. When I enter the number 9, all entries that appear after the 9th entry are your {{/ * Whatever * /}}.

I wanted to show it after all 9 entries.
Example:
9 entries
{{/ * Whatever * /}}
9 entries
{{/ * Whatever * /}}
9 entries
{{/ * Whatever * /}}

Answer (score 1):

This code will spend 10 milliseconds for every x entities. You can change the time(10) as required:

```
{{$x=entities after which you want to spend sometimes;}}        
{{$n=0;}}
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$n++;}}
{{$user->name}}
@if($n == $x)
    {{sleep(10;)}}//here 10 means 10ms
    {{$n=0;}}
@endif
@endforeach
```

This code will spend 10 milliseconds for first x entities. You can change the time(10) as required:

```
{{$x=entities after which you want to spend sometimes;}}    
{{$n=0;}}
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$n++;}}
{{$user->name}}
@if($n == $x)
    {{sleep(10;)}}//here 10 means 10ms
@endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a built-in loop variable. It may help you. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#the-loop-variable).

You can use it like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if ($loop->count == 1)
        {{$user->name}}
    @endif    
@endforeach
```

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know this! but he needs $loop->index and not $loop->count